# Wait for input for only X amount of time

Tags: android, io, wait

I am trying to read in data from an input stream, but if the program does not receive data for X amount of time, I would like to terminate the attempt and return a `-1`. I was previously using `Thread.sleep( X )` but then realized that thats a completely incorrect approach. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Here is my code for reading from the input stream...

```
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
                //break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Future](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to do this.

First, you need a class which will be returned as "future" value:

```
public class ReadResult {
    public final int size;
    public final byte[] buffer;

    public ReadResult(int size, byte[] buffer) {
         this.size = size;
         this.buffer = buffer;
    }
}
```

Then you need to use executor service and use [get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) like this:

```
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<ReadResult> future = service.submit(new Callable<ReadResult>() {

            @Override
            public ReadResult call() throws Exception {
                bytes = mInStream.read(buffer, 0, length);
                return new ReadResult(bytes, buffer);
            }
        });

        ReadResult result = null;
        try {
            result = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // Thread was interrupted
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // Something bad happened during reading
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e1) {
            // read timeout
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            // here you can use it
        }
```

In that way you will be able to achieve your goal. Plz note that its better to subclass Callable class which will accept inputstream as constructor argument then using class variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a new Thread and in there wait for x amount of time. Pass a reference to your activity and once the time is over, you can call a method in your activity from the Time Thread.

eg.

```
Thread time = new Thread() {

Activity foo;

public addActivity(Activity foo) {
this.foo = foo;
}

public void run() {
Thread.sleep(x);
// Once done call method in activity
foo.theTimeHasCome();
}

}.start();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, it seems to be similar to using `Thread.sleep()`. I would like to call `mmInStream.read()`, and if `X amount of time` passes before the `InStream` gets a byte, I would like to return a value of `-1`.